# Android - how do I bring my activity to foreground automatically from Address book

Tags: android

Following is my scenario,

My Activity is running on the foreground and my Activity is getting pushed to background when I hit on the home button... I am trying to display the pop up at certain intervals, in this case as my activity is running on background when I try to display the pop up but thats not shown on the foreground.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 1):

You can't show modal dialogs that way. Use Android's notification system instead.